# how connect to vertica using pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc, unixodbc, vertica

I've read the [iODBC documentation](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/FAQ) regarding the `odbc.ini`, and the [Vertica documentation](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/ProgrammersGuide/InstallingDrivers/CreatingAnODBCDSNForLinuxSolarisAIXAndHP-UX.htm). I also saw a question [with the same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280304/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified), but can't get the connection string to work as suggested in the previous question's answer.

**What I currently have:**

`/etc/odbcinst.ini`

```
[HPVertica]
Description = HP Vertica ODBC Driver
Driver = /opt/vertica/lib64/libverticaodbc.so
```

`/etc/odbc.ini`

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
VerticaDB1 = db1 database on HP Vertica

[VerticaDB1]
Description = db1 database on HP Vertica
Driver = HPVertica
Database = db1
Servername = 10.0.0.67
UID = dbadmin
PWD = 
Port = 5433
Locale = en_GB

[ODBC]
Threading = 1
```

`~/.odbc.ini`

```
[DEFAULT]

Driver = VerticaDB1
```

**Testing with `isql`**

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-67 /]# echo "select 1;" | isql -v VerticaDB1
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL> select 1;
+---------------------+
| ?column?            |
+---------------------+
| 1                   |
+---------------------+
SQLRowCount returns 1
1 rows fetched
```

**`odbcinst -j` outputs:**

```
unixODBC 2.2.14
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

**In Python using "VerticaDB1":**

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={VerticaDB1};UID={dbadmin};PWD={...}")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not 
found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

**In Python using "HPVertica":**

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={HPVertica};UID={dbadmin};PWD={...}")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [unixODBC][Vertica][ODBC] (10430) Not enough 
information provided to establish a connection to the data source and specified 
to not prompt for more information. (10430) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try connecting using `DSN`:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=VerticaDB1;UID=dbadmin;PWD=mypassword")
```

Alternatively, you can connect using `DRIVER`, but you need to supply more information, like which database, host, and port:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER=HPVertica;SERVER=10.0.0.67;DATABASE=db1;PORT=5433;UID=dbadmin;PWD=mypassword")
```

Comment: Using the `DSN` results in the same *Data source name not found...* error. Using `DRIVER` works :)

Comment: On a side note, pyodbc accepts kwargs as well as a string. eg. instead of the first example, you could type: `conn = pyodbc.connect(DSN="VerticaDB1", UID="dbadmin", PWD="mypassword")`. I find this more readable, but the 2 are exactly equivalent.

Comment: This post references some [common odbc/vertica error messages and root causes](http://thisdwhguy.com/2014/04/29/vertica-odbc-error-messages-and-solutions), it might help as I find weird that using `DRIVER` does not work.

Comment: @Guillaume the link is dead unfortunately.

Comment: @alecxe I cannot update the old comment but here is the live link: https://thisdataguy.com/2014/04/29/vertica-odbc-error-messages-and-solutions/