# Error while connecting from Ubuntu to remote SQL Server Express database (on Windows)

Tags: python, sql-server, ubuntu-14.04, pyodbc

I am using Ubuntu system and I want to connect to remote database SQL Express.

I have tried the same using **pyodbc** using following steps.

1. `sudo apt-get install python-pyodbc`
2. Python code as follows :

```
    import pyodbc
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(DRIVER='{SQL Server}', SERVER='REMOTE_SERVER_IP', DATABASE='REMOTE_SERVER_DB_NAME', UID='redbytes', PWD='REMOTE_SERVER_DB_PASSWORD')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

But I am facing problem as follows :

```
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyodbc - "Data source name not found, and no default driver specified"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280304/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified)

Comment: If you're on Ubuntu, are you using the FreeTDS or the MS ODBC driver? You're going to need a driver (I'd recommend FreeTDS) to tell unixODBC how to connect to SQL Server. I'd also recommend against 'apt-get' installing any Python packages, they're very out of date; instead `pip install pyodbc` into a virtualenv.

Comment: I am using FreeTDS and used pip install only

Answer (score 1):

pyodbc is just one part of the puzzle. It's only job is to allow your Python application to communicate with the ODBC subsystem ("Driver Manager"). That layer communicates with the ODBC driver, which in turn talks to the database.

In order to use Python_3 + pyodbc + unixODBC (ODBC driver manager) + FreeTDS (ODBC driver) on Ubuntu the basic steps are:

```
sudo su
apt install python3-pip unixodbc-dev tdsodbc
printf "\n[FreeTDS]\nDriver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so\n" >> /etc/odbcinst.ini 
exit
pip3 install --user pyodbc
```

then use `DRIVER=FreeTDS` in your ODBC connection string (along with `SERVER=`, and other required arguments).