# Linux Open Suse "pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")"

Tags: sql-server, linux

I know this question was asked before but I never really got a proper answer that would solve my problem. I am trying to connect to a SQL server on a windows machine from a linux Open Suse12.4 machine.

```
pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=servername;DATABASE=dbname;UID=userid;PWD=password')
```

the exact error I got was as below:

> pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")

and below is my odbcinst.ini file :

```
[Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server]
Driver=/usr/local/easysoft/sqlserver/lib/libessqlsrv.so
Setup=/usr/local/easysoft/sqlserver/lib/libessqlsrvS.so
Threading=0
FileUsage=1
DontDLClose=1
UsageCount=2

[Easysoft ODBC-SQL Server SSL]
Driver=/usr/local/easysoft/sqlserver/lib/libessqlsrv_ssl.so
Setup=/usr/local/easysoft/sqlserver/lib/libessqlsrvS.so
Threading=0
FileUsage=1
DontDLClose=1
UsageCount=2
```

Comment: See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280304/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified/16280935#16280935) helps.

Comment: thank you so much Benny! the link you sent certainly helped! the issue was my odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini files were in /etc/. however, running odbcinst -j shows that those 2 files suppose to be at /etc/unixODBC/. so i just copied over the file and it solved my problem! thank you again

Comment: @BarathanR is this issue resolved then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyodbc - "Data source name not found, and no default driver specified"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280304/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified)

Comment: Are you absolute sure your driver packages have been installed? I had similar error messages when python could not connect to OBDC driver.

Answer (score 1):

This post helped me to pinpoint my issue. My situation is that i have install the ODBC driver following this post "https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-RHEL-6-or-Centos-7" and turn out, i found that DRIVER "SQL Server" does not exist in my ini file. I changed DRIVER in connection string as "cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=XXXXX;Database=XXX;Uid=XXX;Pwd=XXX;")" and it works

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an offline REHL server, then follow the below method to setup connection to Microsoft SQL Server.

1. Download UNIXODBC & MSSQLTools packages—e.g., `unixODBC-2.3.7-1.rh.x86_64.rpm/mssql-tools-17.9.1.1-1.x86_64.rpm`—from [the Microsoft repo](https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/), as per your REHL version
2. Place downloaded files on the REHL server via winscp or any ssh client
3. Install these two files in sequence given below:

   - ```
     yum localinstall unixODBC-2.3.7-1.rh.x86_64.rpm
     ```
   - ```
     yum localinstall mssql-tools-17.9.1.1-1.x86_64.rpm)
     ```
4. Go to the installation folder and copy the path as shown in e.g.,

   ```
   /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1
   ```
5. Put this path in code:

   ```
   driverpath = r"/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.9.so.1.1"
   ```

Your problem will get solved.

Answer (score 0):

Pyodbc is not able to locate Driver = {SQL Server} used. In my case, It was mainly because the name I gave in odbcinst.ini file and related files wasn't correct.

Instead using 
Driver =/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib; using in connection uri helped me connect and hence understand that my configuration files were incorrect.

- Different types of libraries for connecting to SQL Server installed which causes the conflict.

I corrected it and was able to connect.