# Zappa deployment error : GET request yields 502 response code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, zappa, flask-ask

I am trying to deploy the first zappa example app built with Flask-Ask, It looks like everything works good but after the Deploying API statement I get the following error :

Error: Warning! Status check on the deployed lambda failed. A GET request to '/'
yielded a 502 response code.

Here is the code I am executing with minor changes to the sample app

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_ask import Ask, question, statement, session
import pyodbc

app = Flask(name)
ask = Ask(app, '/')

@ask.intent('HelloIntent')
def hello(firstname):
speech_text = "Hello %s" % firstname
return statement(speech_text).simple_card('Hello', speech_text)

@ask.intent('ByeIntent')
def bye():
return statement("Ok, goodBye!")



if name == 'main':
app.run()
```

- Zappa version used: 0.46.1
- Operating System and Python version: Windows 7, Python 3.6

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Could you please make one change at a time to the sample app, then identify a single line that causes your problem? Introducing an entire new library is not a minor change--in particular, adding Alexa means that there's a whole set of permissions that could be coming into play. Did you look at your Cloudwatch logs?

Comment: Would not changing `app.run()` to `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)` be necessary?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try installing all the dependencies using pip in the virtual environment where you are using zappa. It worked in my case.

You can also use `zappa tail` command to see your logs.

Comment: Good advice! I can see the error as : pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC
Driver 11 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)") The same code works on my local environment though

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49269603/7546606) helps

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot.  I had forgotten to pip install flask.  Not sure how it was working locally...

Comment: `Flask` was certainly installed _system-wide_ by another package

Answer (score 2):

This [github issue](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa/issues/1536) seems to have the same symptoms. 
Downgrading to `zappa==0.45.1` solved it for me

Answer (score 2):

If you are using anaconda than create a new virtual environment "virtualenv lambda" in your project directory and in Scripts/activate. Than deactivate the conda environment with "conda deactivate" and pip install all the packages "pip install numpy pandas sklearn zappa flask".

PS: using "slim_handle"=true also gives this error, so don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

If all of above doesn't work you can solve it by this way.

- First solve all errors by checking the app log by `zappa tail [app name]`, if you have any

Then,
You must provide `"app_function"` parameter in the `zappa_settings.json` which should point to your entry function. The app_function should be provided like this if application is Flask `__init__.application`, so the flask app should be defined as `application` as follows,

```
application = Flask(__name__)
```

app.py should be `__init__.py`
You have to add `__init__.py` in order to recognize your project folder as a package. 
So `zappa_settings.json` have parameter like this,

`"app_function": "__init__.application",`

Deploy and enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this error when I gave the modular path to my application as `main.py`.

I fixed it by creating an empty file called `main.app` just next to `main.py` and setting `app_function` to `main.app` in `zappa_settings.json`.

Absolutely no clue what happened underneath, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. After spending couple of hours, from cloudwatch logs I noticed the error of sec certificate. Solved it by running "pip install 'cryptography<2.2'"

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error, and same what happened with ScottieB above, the reason was that I forgot to do the pip install for one package that my .app was using...After I did the pip install locally in the project environment then did the `zappa update dev` the error gone! and update been completed.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and after many online searches and trying many, many suggestions, it was actually just a small problem with a code indentation! No problem with Zappa config or pip installations at all.

I notice that in your code sample you have not indented your code at all. I don't know if this is how it copy pasted into StackOverflow or if this is how you unintentionally tried to deploy it. It should be

```
@ask.intent('HelloIntent')
def hello(firstname):
    speech_text = "Hello %s" % firstname
    return statement(speech_text).simple_card('Hello', speech_text)

@ask.intent('ByeIntent')
def bye():
    return statement("Ok, goodBye!")


if name == 'main':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error. 
check you have installed zappa in your venv. 
I have installed globally and run in local venv. When i installed zappa it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and I figured out that zappa is installed globally on my system not in the virtual env that I am using.

try installing zappa in virtual env

```
pip install zappa
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running a flask app and forgot to include following statement in my app.

`if __name__ == '__main__': app.run()`

after adding this line it started working fine.