# InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0)

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook, pyodbc

Where can I check at first to resolve the following error message?
I would like to connect to SQL Server on Docker, from a Mac using Jupyter notebook.

## code

```
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://SA:<12345qwert>@MSSQL_DSN")
connection = engine.connect()
```

## error message

> InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280304/pyodbc-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-default-driver-specified

Comment: I would start with `odbcinst -j` and `isql MSSQL_DSN sa "<12345qwert>"`

Comment: Thank you everyone! 
I resolved this problem by execute below command

`$ cp /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini /etc/odbc.ini`
`$ cp /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.ini`